# Erlang newbie - concurrency and message passing

Tags: concurrency, erlang, spawn, erl, spawning

I'm still new to programming and brand new erlang (2 week newbie!). I edited slightly so atleast it'll compile and run. But I still can't figure out the concept of sending the results to a "joiner process" to join all the seperate results.

It does split and send the "chunks" an received to count the chunks. Just don't know how to get all those processes to join their individual results. I sort of understand the concept below, but have no idea how that's implimented. I've been trying for many days and hours to get it to this point, but can't get it to do anything without getting errors or unbound variables, etc.

```
-module (ccharcount1d).
-compile(export_all).

load(F)->
 {ok, Bin} = file:read_file(F),
  List=binary_to_list(Bin),
  Ls=string:to_lower(List),
  Length=round(length(List)/20),
  Collect_Results = spawn(ccharcount1d, collect_results, []),

  Sl=split(Ls,Length),

  io:fwrite("Loaded, Split, and sent to multiple processes~n").




%%splits txt file into "chunks" and sends those "chunks" to be processed 
split([],_)->[];
split(List,Length)->
S1=string:substr(List,1,Length),
case length(List) > Length of
   true->S2=string:substr(List,Length+1,length(List)),
   Process_Split = spawn(ccharcount1d,receive_splits,[]),
   Process_Split ! {self(), S1};

   false->S2=[],
   Process_Split = spawn(ccharcount1d,receive_splits,[]),
   Process_Split ! {self(), S1}   

 end,  

[S1]++split(S2,Length).


%%recieves the split "chunks" and counts the results 
receive_splits()-> 
    receive
        {From, S1} -> 
            Result=go(S1)
            %Collect_Results ! Result
    end.



collect_results()-> 
    receive
        {Process_Split, Result} ->
            Result=join([],Result)
    end.



join([],[])->[];
join([],R)->R;
join([H1 |T1],[H2|T2])->
{C,N}=H1,
{C1,N1}=H2,
[{C1,N+N1}]++join(T1,T2).



count(Ch, [],N)->N;
count(Ch, [H|T],N) ->
   case Ch==H of
   true-> count(Ch,T,N+1);
   false -> count(Ch,T,N)
end.

go(L)->
Alph=[$a,$b,$c,$d,$e,$f,$g,$h,$i,$j,$k,$l,$m,$n,$o,$p,$q,$r,$s,$t,$u,$v,$w,$x,$y,$z],
rgo(Alph,L,[]).

rgo([H|T],L,Result)->
N=count(H,L,0),
Result2=Result++[{[H],N}],
rgo(T,L,Result2);


rgo([],L,Result)-> Result.
```

Comment: *I'm still new to programming and brand new erlang (2 week newbie!)*  Terrible idea in my opinion.  Learn python.  Spend a year having fun with it, then decide where you want to go from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> again, i'm new. I'm understanding the concept. I'm not understanding
>   the syntax. the how to "pass a Pid to a worker process"

```
start() ->
    Work = ...,
    JoinPid = spawn(fun() -> join_func([]) end),  
    WorkerPid = spawn(fun() -> worker_func(JoinPid, Work) end),  %Pass JoinPid to worker process.
    ...

join_func(Acc) ->
    receive
        Result ->
            join_func([Result|Acc]);  %Recursive function call--the life blood of all functional languages.

        ...
    end

worker_func(JoinPid, Work) ->
    Result = ... Work ...,
    JoinPid ! Result.  %Worker process uses JoinPid to send back the results.
```

Also, check out this:

```
8> [$a, $b, $c].
"abc"

9> "abc".
"abc"
```

The output shows that `[$a, $b, $c]` is equivalent to `"abc"`.  That means you can write this:

```
[$a,$b,$c,$d,$e,$f,$g,$h,$i,$j,$k,$l,$m,$n,$o,$p,$q,$r,$s,$t,$u,$v,$w,$x,$y,$z]
```

much more succinctly like this:

```
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

and even more so, like this:

```
11> lists:seq(97, 122).
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to synchronize the output of go function.
Don't spawn function inside go because i am seeing that all results are going to different process(receive_results).

Best solutions is spawn one process for joining result inside load function only(this process takes self() as Input so that it can send final result back to load function).Then pass that join process reference(J_PID) to all worker processes which will send back result to join process.Join process is loop of kind of receive_results.Loop terminates when all chunks are processed.Add a clause to terminate join process.While terminating, join process will send back result to load function.

Sudo code:

J_PID = spawn join(self())
spilt(J_PID,....)
wait_for_result(receive Result -> R)

Comment: Ok, sorry but I'm only 2 weeks into programming and Erlang, Theres alot in what you said that I need to breakdown to understand. On thing I need to do is if I'm understanding correctly, I need to remove this:

DELETE `rgo([],L,Result)->`
DELTETE `Process_Results = spawn(ccharcount1d, receive_results, []),`
DELETE `Process_Results ! {self(), Result}.`

Put in place simply `rgo([],L,Result) -> Result.`

Comment: then in the load function, after `io:format("Load, split......),` I could spawn the join process.

Comment: you kind of lost me. I see what you mean that the results are then off to different processes. but i'm not quite understanding "the pass join process to worker process part"

Comment: To get result in one process, worker process who will be processing chunks should know which is joining proceas so that it can send result to that process.That way all worker process will send result to one process.

Comment: ok, but how exactly is that coded? im confused, but I'm trying to learn. So each worker process will do its count on the chunk. The result from that chunk (and all the other chunks), then will need to be sent to 1 process (the Join process)? And I'm sorry, but I need to see explicitly how that looks.

`load(F)->
{ok, Bin} = file:read_file(F),
   List=binary_to_list(Bin),
   Ls=string:to_lower(List),
   Length=round(length(List)/20),
   Collect_Results = spawn(ccharcount1d, join, self()),   
   Sl=split(Ls,Length),
   io:fwrite("Loaded, Split, and sent to multiple processes~n").`

Comment: You understood correctly. You have to pass Collect_Results(Pid) to chunk process as argument so that it can send back result. You have to write join function such a way that it will receive and accumulate result from all chunk worker processes.Collect result process will accumulate all results.

Comment: again, i'm new. I'm understanding the concept. I'm not understanding the syntax. the how to "pass a Pid to a worker process". I don't know what that looks like.

Comment: @chitown88, maybe would be better if you start reading some book about programming on Erlang.

Comment: @chitown88, if you have simple questions about Erlang, you also can ask it in the [Erlang chat-room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75358/erlang-otp).

Comment: You have already passed self() Pid to collect_results Process.Same way you can pass Collect_results pid to worker process(same syntax).